# Customized kernal always dies in sagemaker jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I was able to create a customized kernel by using

> conda create -n myenv python=3.8 -y

and the customized env `myenv` works fine in sagemaker terminal. However, when trying to use kernel `myenv` within a sagemaker notebook, the kernal was there but will almost always die (more than 90% of the time and by luck it will work) and returns to showing `no kernel`. This happens for whatever simple python command I tried to run in a notebook cell. WTF is sagemaker doing that can't even work with such a trivial functionality?

Comment: Hi, are you able to view the custom kernel, i.e., have ipykernel installed in your `myenv`? I can't reproduce the error, but is there any chance you're running OOM running other kernels/notebooks? If so, try switching to a larger instance and see if the error persists.

Comment: Instead of using jupyterlab where the notebook just dies without showing any useful message, I tried using jupyter to switch to the customized kernel. Now I'm able to see the error msg of `Connection Failed` from jupyter: `
A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.` It is still hard to interpret the msg though. I'm running on a `ml.m5.2xlarge` instance.

Comment: Any chance you can try it on m5.4xl? Also, is your notebook on JupyterLab version 3? It has better retry mechanisms for connection errors.